# SSL Cert on Seperate Email Server and Web Hosting Server?

Tags: email, iis, ssl, https, hosting

I am working with a client who needs SSL on their Email and Web Site.
We have their site hosted on a Rackspace Cloud Site (Wordpress so Apache and all that jazz).
From what I can tell their Email is on an ISS server of their own.

They want to apply this SSL Cert they bought through GoDaddy and apply it to this email server and to the site on our hosting server. Now I am only a Web Developer with enough server knowledge to get sites launched and running, But I don't think you can apply the same SSL Cert on two different types of servers.

What would the solution be for this?
Would you purchase a second ssl? Is that even possible?

Sorry if this is a all completely wrong I am trying to use my limited knowledge of SSL to describe the situation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can use the same certificate if it's going on two servers as long as they are both using the same domain.  You don't need to purchase a second ssl.  The tricky part might be if the two servers require different certificate file formats.

Also, just do the CSR part on ONE of the servers (use the one you trust the most).  On the other server just install the certificate bypassing the CSR part.